# Frequently restart Kubernetes pod leads to CrashLoopBack

Tags: testing, kubernetes

During functional testing, we would like to restart a specific Kubernetes pod after each test case to reset the status of the application. But frequently executing `kubectl delete pod` leads to very slow pod restart.
Is there any way I can configure the policy for this pod to avoid slow pod restart?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is normal depending upon various factors like infrastructure, network, cpu, memory etc. I would recommend you to scale up/down to 0,1 to test the changes made the deployment which would save time.